# Data cleaning, from cross-sectional (multiple files) to panel in RStudio: merge/gather?

Tags: r, merge, key

I have yearly observations for individuals on different variables from 2008-2020. I have data on family (25 variables), income (15 variables), and schooling (22 variables).
Right now, have 'cleaned' every single dataset so that every column of every category has the same column name. For context, this is what my R looks like now.

[image]

The thing is, I would like to have one big dataset with all of the individuals and years in one dataframe. I know that I should/could use the innerjoin or merge function first of all sorting by 'Householdmember', and that I could use the gather function, but I am truly struggling in what order I should do this and where I should start. I've been trying a lot of things, but considering the number of dataframes, it's hard to keep track of what I'm doing. I also created lists of every category for every year because this was recommended in one method, but that did not work out...

I want to end up with a dataframe that looks similar to this:

| Individual | Year | Var1 | Var2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2008 | value | value |
| 1 | 2009 | value | value |
| 1 | 2010 | value | value |
| 2 | 2008 | value | value |
| 2 | 2009 | value | value |
| 2 | 2010 | value | value |

What I should do as first step... If I merge the dataframes, I don't think R knows which values correspond to which year...

```
    > head(fam08)
# A tibble: 6 x 25
  HouseholdMember RandomChild YearBirthRandom  Gender   Age FatherBirth FatherAlive MotherBirth MotherAlive Divorce SeeFather SeeMother
            <dbl>   <dbl+lbl>           <dbl> <dbl+l> <dbl>   <dbl+lbl>   <dbl+lbl>   <dbl+lbl>   <dbl+lbl> <dbl+l> <dbl+lbl> <dbl+lbl>
1          800033 16 [not ap…              NA 1 [mal…    16        1952     1 [yes]        1961     1 [yes] 1 [yes]  7 [ever…  7 [ever…
2          800042 16 [not ap…              NA 2 [fem…    32        1946     1 [yes]        1948     1 [yes] 2 [no]   4 [at l…  4 [at l…
3          800045 16 [not ap…              NA 1 [mal…    65        1913     2 [no]         1915     2 [no]  2 [no]  NA        NA       
4          800057 16 [not ap…              NA 1 [mal…    33        1939     1 [yes]        1945     1 [yes] 1 [yes]  4 [at l…  4 [at l…
5          800076 16 [not ap…              NA 2 [fem…    22        1955     1 [yes]        1955     1 [yes] 1 [yes]  5 [at l…  3 [a fe…
6          800119 16 [not ap…              NA 2 [fem…    57        1908     2 [no]         1918     2 [no]  2 [no]  NA        NA       
# … with 13 more variables: Married <dbl+lbl>, Child <dbl+lbl>, NumChild <dbl>, SchoolCH1 <dbl+lbl>, SchoolCH2 <dbl+lbl>,
#   SchoolCH3 <dbl+lbl>, SchoolCH4 <dbl+lbl>, BirthCH1 <dbl>, BirthCH2 <dbl>, BirthCH3 <dbl>, BirthCH4 <dbl>, FamSatisfaction <dbl+lbl>,
#   Year <dbl>



> head(fam09)
# A tibble: 6 x 25
  HouseholdMember RandomChild YearBirthRandom  Gender   Age FatherBirth FatherAlive MotherBirth MotherAlive Divorce SeeFather SeeMother
            <dbl>   <dbl+lbl>           <dbl> <dbl+l> <dbl>   <dbl+lbl>   <dbl+lbl>   <dbl+lbl>   <dbl+lbl> <dbl+l> <dbl+lbl> <dbl+lbl>
1          800033 16 [not ap…              NA 1 [mal…    17        1952     1 [yes]        1961     1 [yes]      NA  5 [at l…  7 [ever…
2          800042 16 [not ap…              NA 2 [fem…    33        1946     1 [yes]        1948     1 [yes]      NA  4 [at l…  4 [at l…
3          800057 16 [not ap…              NA 1 [mal…    34        1939     1 [yes]        1945     1 [yes]      NA  3 [a fe…  3 [a fe…
4          800076 16 [not ap…              NA 2 [fem…    23        1955     1 [yes]        1955     1 [yes]      NA  5 [at l…  3 [a fe…
5          800119 16 [not ap…              NA 2 [fem…    58          NA    NA                NA    NA            NA NA        NA       
6          800125 16 [not ap…              NA 2 [fem…    50          NA    NA              1928     1 [yes]      NA NA         1 [neve…
# … with 13 more variables: Married <dbl+lbl>, Child <dbl+lbl>, NumChild <dbl>, SchoolCH1 <dbl+lbl>, SchoolCH2 <dbl+lbl>,
#   SchoolCH3 <dbl+lbl>, SchoolCH4 <dbl+lbl>, BirthCH1 <dbl>, BirthCH2 <dbl>, BirthCH3 <dbl>, BirthCH4 <dbl>, FamSatisfaction <dbl+lbl>,
#   Year <dbl>




dput(head(fam09,10))
structure(list(HouseholdMember = c(800033, 800042, 800057, 800076, 
800119, 800125, 800170, 800186, 800201, 800204), RandomChild = structure(c(16, 
16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 3, 16, 16, 16), label = "Randomly chosen child", labels = c(`child 1` = 1, 
`child 2` = 2, `child 3` = 3, `child 4` = 4, `child 5` = 5, `child 6` = 6, 
`child 7` = 7, `child 8` = 8, `child 9` = 9, `child 10` = 10, 
`child 11` = 11, `child 12` = 12, `child 13` = 13, `child 14` = 14, 
`child 15` = 15, `not applicable` = 16), class = "haven_labelled"), 
    YearBirthRandom = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1999, NA, NA, 
    NA), Gender = structure(c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1), label = "Gender respondent", labels = c(male = 1, 
    female = 2), class = "haven_labelled"), Age = c(17, 33, 34, 
    23, 58, 50, 50, 69, 35, 67), FatherBirth = structure(c(1952, 
    1946, 1939, 1955, NA, NA, 1926, NA, 1948, NA), label = "What is the year of birth of your father?", labels = c(`I don't know` = 99999), class = "haven_labelled"), 
    FatherAlive = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA
    ), label = "Is your father still alive?", labels = c(yes = 1, 
    no = 2, `I don't know` = 99), class = "haven_labelled"), 
    MotherBirth = structure(c(1961, 1948, 1945, 1955, NA, 1928, 
    1931, NA, 1950, NA), label = "What is the year of birth of your mother?", labels = c(`I don't know` = 99999), class = "haven_labelled"), 
    MotherAlive = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA
    ), label = "Is your mother still alive?", labels = c(yes = 1, 
    no = 2, `I don't know` = 99), class = "haven_labelled"), 
    Divorce = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), label = "Did your own parents ever divorce?", labels = c(yes = 1, 
    no = 2, `my parents never had a relationship` = 3, `I don't know` = 99
    ), class = "haven_labelled"), SeeFather = structure(c(5, 
    4, 3, 5, NA, NA, 6, NA, 3, NA), label = "How often did you see your father over the past 12 months?", labels = c(never = 1, 
    once = 2, `a few times` = 3, `at least every month` = 4, 
    `at least every week` = 5, `a few times per week` = 6, `every day` = 7
    ), class = "haven_labelled"), SeeMother = structure(c(7, 
    4, 3, 3, NA, 1, 6, NA, 3, NA), label = "How often did you see your mother over the past 12 months?", labels = c(never = 1, 
    once = 2, `a few times` = 3, `at least every month` = 4, 
    `at least every week` = 5, `a few times per week` = 6, `every day` = 7
    ), class = "haven_labelled"), Married = structure(c(NA, 1, 
    2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1), label = "Are you married to this partner?", labels = c(yes = 1, 
    no = 2), class = "haven_labelled"), Child = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), label = "Have you had any children?", labels = c(yes = 1, 
    no = 2), class = "haven_labelled"), NumChild = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), SchoolCH1 = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA), label = "What school does child 1 (born in the years 1991 through 2004) attend?", labels = c(`primary school` = 1, 
    `school for special primary education` = 2, `secondary school` = 3, 
    other = 4), class = "haven_labelled"), SchoolCH2 = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA), label = "What school does child 2 (born in the years 1991 through 2004) attend?", labels = c(`primary school` = 1, 
    `school for special primary education` = 2, `secondary school` = 3, 
    other = 4), class = "haven_labelled"), SchoolCH3 = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA), label = "What school does child 3 (born in the years 1991 through 2004) attend?", labels = c(`primary school` = 1, 
    `school for special primary education` = 2, `secondary school` = 3, 
    other = 4), class = "haven_labelled"), SchoolCH4 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), label = "What school does child 4 (born in the years 1991 through 2004) attend?", labels = c(`primary school` = 1, 
    `school for special primary education` = 2, `secondary school` = 3, 
    other = 4), class = "haven_labelled"), BirthCH1 = c(NA, 2005, 
    2007, NA, 1983, NA, 1991, 1964, NA, 1974), BirthCH2 = c(NA, 
    2007, NA, NA, 1985, NA, 1994, 1966, NA, 1976), BirthCH3 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1999, 1970, NA, NA), BirthCH4 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), FamSatisfaction = structure(c(NA, 
    8, 9, NA, 8, NA, 8, NA, NA, NA), label = "How satisfied are you with your family life?", labels = c(`entirely dissatisfied` = 0, 
    `entirely satisfied` = 10, `I don’t know` = 999), class = "haven_labelled"), 
    Year = c(2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 
    2009, 2009)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I updated the question with the heads of the dataframes

Comment: Please use `dput()` to share the data structures (eg `dput(head(fam08,10))` )

Comment: I added the output for dput() for the 2009 dataframe!

Comment: seems like you could row bind all the frames of the same type to create three frames and the use left joins (or inner joins if you were okay dropping incomplete rows), joining on HouseholdMember and Year

Comment: Thank you so much langtang! By doing this, it worked for me! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could do something along these lines:

```
fam = bind_rows(fam_list)
inc = bind_rows(inc_list)
ws = bind_rows(ws_list)

result = fam %>%
  left_join(inc, by=c("HouseholdMember", "Year")) %>% 
  left_join(ws, by=c("HouseholdMember", "Year"))
```

Output:

```
   HouseholdMember  Year fam_v1 fam_v2 fam_v3  inc_v1  inc_v2 inc_v3   ws_v1 ws_v2  ws_v3
             <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1            8001  2008  0.609 -0.253 -1.30   0.0147  0.719  -0.765  0.120  0.974 -0.764
 2            8002  2008  0.395  1.73  -0.503  0.119  -3.33   -0.798  0.325  0.664  1.65 
 3            8003  2008  0.562  0.157  0.243 -1.18   -0.260   0.105  1.09   0.855  1.19 
 4            8004  2008  1.32   0.737 -1.18   0.725  -1.82    0.356  0.362  2.04   1.76 
 5            8005  2008 -0.497 -0.444 -0.632 -0.534   1.63    0.984  1.29   0.614  0.576
 6            8006  2008 -1.70  -0.989 -1.32   0.868   0.0979  0.468 -0.0146 1.11   0.957
 7            8007  2008 -2.19  -0.419  1.69   1.34   -0.404  -1.43  -0.156  0.648 -0.186
 8            8008  2008  1.48   0.350 -0.595  0.785  -0.609   1.28  -1.01   1.04   0.845
 9            8009  2008 -0.315 -0.530  0.419  0.390  -0.0951 -0.755  0.135  0.696 -1.97 
10            8010  2008 -0.882  1.38   2.06  -0.0757  1.53   -0.494 -1.03   1.14   1.87
```

### Note:

I manufactured the data for this example by creating a lists of tibbles; I believe the `fam_list`, `inc_list`, and `ws_list` are similar to the list objects in your image. These are list of data frames / tibbles.  I then use `bind_rows` to bind these similar structure tibbles together so that I have a three large tibbles.

I then use `left_join` twice to join `inc` and `ws` to `fam`

### Input Data:

```
library(tidyverse)
fam_list = lapply(8:20, function(x) {
  tibble(HouseholdMember = c(8000+seq(1:100)),
         Year=2000+x, 
         fam_v1=rnorm(100), 
         fam_v2=rnorm(100), 
         fam_v3=rnorm(100)
  )
})
names(fam_list) = paste0("fam_20", 8:20)

inc_list = lapply(8:20, function(x) {
  tibble(HouseholdMember = c(8000+seq(1:100)),
         Year=2000+x, 
         inc_v1=rnorm(100), 
         inc_v2=rnorm(100), 
         inc_v3=rnorm(100)
  )
})
names(inc_list) = paste0("inc_20", 8:20)
ws_list = lapply(8:20, function(x) {
  tibble(HouseholdMember = c(8000+seq(1:100)),
         Year=2000+x, 
         ws_v1=rnorm(100), 
         ws_v2=rnorm(100), 
         ws_v3=rnorm(100)
  )
})
names(ws_list) = paste0("ws_20", 8:20)
```

Input